# Definition of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I am just puzzled by an observation I made on undergraduate texts in Real Analysis. The concepts of supremum and infimum are not particularly easy to grasp for students who are fresh to the subject, and it is surely a lot easier for them to understand the maximum and minimum of a set (including the fact that they may not exist) and of upper bounds. All one has to do is point out intervals such as $[0,2]$ and $[0,2)$ and talk about the number 2 and the number 3. So why not define the least upper bound of a set $S$ (in an ordered field) as the minimum (it it exists) of the set of all upper bounds for $S$?

I have examined a large number of undergraduate texts for Real Analysis, and I have never found this simple definition, or the word "minimum" even mentioned. Most of the them will define it using the much more difficult way "it's an upper bound, and for any number strictly less than it, there will be some etc. etc. ". A few will say: it is an upper bound $M$ such that if $x$ is an upper bound, then $M\leq x$. Again, why not say, "it's the minimum of the set of all upper bounds"?  Some will just say "it's the least upper bound" but even this is a change of language, from minimum to least, and in any case they use "least upper bound" as just the name for the concept, then going on to define it using the convoluted way.

I do not mean to post this as a topic of discussion, only as a genuine question on whether I am missing something important that will explain why it is a good idea to define supremum that way.

Comment: I just checked the half dozen undergraduate real analysis texts on my shelves. **None** of them uses your first definition. Five use your second definition. One says that it’s an upper bound with the property that the set has no smaller upper bound, which in the case of a linear order is equivalent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  There must be a large number of Real Analysis texts, and we probably looked at different ones. I asked four different people who teach it to recommend one and they all gave me various lists and no two books were the same. I do not have all of them now but S.Lay's  "Analysis and introduction to proof" and R. Gordon's "Analysis - a first course" use my first definition, and I do not remember any book defining it as the minimum of the set of upper bounds. It's true that "least upper bound" is saying just that, bur why not use the same word introduced just before, minimum.

Comment: You’re making an unwarranted assumption: there is absolutely no reason to think that the word *minimum* **was** introduced just before the definition of supremum/infimum. And *least upper bound* is, frankly, self-explanatory.